# Do I need std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

Please consider next class. Does `std::forward` required here?

```
class Class1
{
public:
    using ContainerT = std::map<Key,Value>;
public:
    static ContainerT const& vibrometers(){ 
        return vibrometers_();  // std::forward?
    }
protected:
    static ContainerT & vibrometers_(){ 
        static ContainerT vibrometers__;  // no duplicate declaration in cpp
        return vibrometers__;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you would need `std::forward` here?

Comment: You tell us. Are there any *forwarding* references in your class?

Comment: So, to spell it out: no. You're not potentially forwarding rvalue references. You're returning const references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `forward` is a conditional move (it is a move iff the type passed in `<>` is a value or rvalue reference).

There is no circumstance where you are moving a `ContainerT` on that line.

So you should not `forward`.

This does not mean all conditional moves should be forwards, but there are very few conditional moves that shouldn't be forwards.